# Summing the scores of specific items in Sorted Set

Tags: redis

Other answers give are outdated

The only option I found in the docs is `ZUNIONSCORE` which is great, but it forces me to save the results somewhere, and then fetch to retrieve it.

Is there a way to do the sum, on redis side, and not save the results? (since then I need to manually expire it)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [Lua scripting](http://redis.io/commands/EVAL) embedded in Redis.